# extracting information from my XML file and assign a vector to that

Tags: python, xml, nlp

I want to parse a few  XML file on my computer  in python and extract some information from each of them

here is my xml file of one of them :

[image]

(if you want the text is here :
https://github.com/peldszus/arg-microtexts/blob/master/corpus/en/micro_b002.xml)

as first level, I have done the first level as so:

```
myList = []                #read the whole text from 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xml'):
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), encoding="UTF-8") as content:
                tree = ET.parse(content)
                myList.append(tree)
```

in myList I have  a few XMl file
<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree at 0x1f0fb1f8430>

now for the root "edge" which they **DO NOT**  have type="seg"

```
 <edge id="c1" src="a1" trg="a3" type="sup"/>
  <edge id="c2" src="a2" trg="a3" type="sup"/>
  <edge id="c4" src="a4" trg="a3" type="reb"/>
  <edge id="c5" src="a5" trg="c4" type="und"/>
```

I want to extract tags   "src"    those I want to extract tag=Src,

```
  src="a1"  
  src="a2"  
  src="a4" 
  src="a5"
```

then I want to assign the number  is not appread in the src,  as  the sentence called premise ,e.g. here...I want to say that  "a3" is so called "premise"  (as it is not  as tag src)

here for instance

(0,0,1,0,0) should be result of my process as a3 is not appread I put the 3rd array as 1, the rest as zero

generally, I want to extract information in order to annotate my text which has been some how annotated using xml

Answer (score 1):

Not everything is clear in your question...
Below is the data extraction part

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<arggraph id="micro_b002" topic_id="higher_dog_poo_fines" stance="pro">
  <edu id="e1"><![CDATA[One can hardly move in Friedrichshain or Neukölln these days without permanently scanning the ground for dog dirt.]]></edu>
  <edu id="e2"><![CDATA[And when bad luck does strike and you step into one of the many 'land mines' you have to painstakingly scrape the remains off your soles.]]></edu>
  <edu id="e3"><![CDATA[Higher fines are therefore the right measure against negligent, lazy or simply thoughtless dog owners.]]></edu>
  <edu id="e4"><![CDATA[Of course, first they'd actually need to be caught in the act by public order officers,]]></edu>
  <edu id="e5"><![CDATA[but once they have to dig into their pockets, their laziness will sure vanish!]]></edu>
  <adu id="a1" type="pro"/>
  <adu id="a2" type="pro"/>
  <adu id="a3" type="pro"/>
  <adu id="a4" type="opp"/>
  <adu id="a5" type="pro"/>
  <edge id="c6" src="e1" trg="a1" type="seg"/>
  <edge id="c7" src="e2" trg="a2" type="seg"/>
  <edge id="c8" src="e3" trg="a3" type="seg"/>
  <edge id="c9" src="e4" trg="a4" type="seg"/>
  <edge id="c10" src="e5" trg="a5" type="seg"/>
  <edge id="c1" src="a1" trg="a3" type="sup"/>
  <edge id="c2" src="a2" trg="a3" type="sup"/>
  <edge id="c4" src="a4" trg="a3" type="reb"/>
  <edge id="c5" src="a5" trg="c4" type="und"/>
</arggraph>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
interesting_edges_src = [e.attrib['src'] for e in root.findall('.//edge') if e.attrib['type'] != 'seg' ]
print(interesting_edges_src)
```

output

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5']
```

Answer (score 0):

using @balderman response, here could be consider as kind of answer which somehow close to the final one

```
myList = []  
myEdgesList=[]
#read the whole text from 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xml'):
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), encoding="UTF-8") as content:
                tree = ET.parse(content)
                myList.append(tree)
```

```
for k in myList:
    Edge= [e.attrib['src'] for e in k.findall('.//edge') if e.attrib['type'] != 'seg' ]
    myEdgesList.append(Edge)
```

this provide

['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5'] for the example above and also a list for all other example

```
[['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
 ['a2', 'a3'],
 ['a2', 'a3'],
 ['a2', 'a3'],
 ['a2', 'a3'],
 ['a2', 'a3'],
 ['a2', 'a3'],
 ['a2', 'a3'],
 ['a2', 'a3'],
 ['a2', 'a3'],
 ['a2', 'a3'],
 ['a2', 'a3'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
 ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
 ['a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'],
.
.
.
```

only it remained to convert this list to

```
(0,0,0,0,1) <----- ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']

#as a5 is missing 


(0,0,1,0,0) <------  ['a1', 'a2', 'a4', 'a5']

#as a3 is misisng 
.
.
.
(0,0,1)    <-------   ['a2', 'a3']

#as a1 is missing
```

and so on

if you have any idea let me know, I am working on that also

Answer (score 0):

for the next question

```
myEdgtlistmap=[]
for lst in myEdgesList:
    tp=[]
    for el in lst:
        if el=="a1":
            tp.append(1)
        if el=="a2":
            tp.append(2)
        if el=="a3":
            tp.append(3)
        if el=="a4":
            tp.append(4)
        if el=="a5":
            tp.append(5)
        if el=="a6":
            tp.append(6)
    myEdgtlistmap.append(tp)
```

```
label=[]
for le in myEdgtlistmap:
    b=[1]*(len(le)+1)
    for v in le: 
        b[v-1]=0
    label.append(b)
```

```
y=[l for lab in label for l in lab ]
```